# What is the correct form of conferences/proceedings/transactions name in a citation?

Tags: citations

I usually try to get citation from publishers website and import it into a reference manager like endnote. I have doubt about the correct form of conferences/proceedings/transactions name in citation. As an example, the provided citation for [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6253489) in IEEE format is this:

> D. Bi-Ru and I. C. Lin, "Efficient Map/Reduce-Based DBSCAN Algorithm
> with Optimized Data Partition," in **Cloud Computing (CLOUD), 2012 IEEE
> 5th International Conference on, 2012**, pp. 59-66.

It seems to be misplaced but as you could see in the "**published in**" section of IEEE webpage of the paper, the conference name is the same as this citation.

The same holds for proceedings and transactions.

Is this way of citation correct?

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that the reason citations are done this way (and now we're verging on [english.se](http://english.stackexchange.com) territory) is to allow for meaningful alphabetical ordering/indexing.

In this case, the "IEEE transactions on" is the generic part of the name, and should not be used for alphabetical ordering/indexing. This is analogous to how in indices you'll often see things like

> Korea, Republic of

rather than

> Republic of Korea.

Comment: i always thought that particular case was because it is easier to keep track of 'Korea', since there are two one is 'Republic of' other is 'Democratic Peoples Republic of'

Comment: That's just it. You want to index based on the most likely term, because people will look for Korea under K. Similarly, if I'm looking for a Cloud Computing journal, I want to look under C rather than attempt to guess if it's IEEE or Transactions and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Venue names are often inconsistent in such a manner. Even if you take your citations from a single source (e.g., [DBLP](http://www.informatik.uni-trier.de/~ley/db/)), you will sometimes find different names for the same venue across different years.

When citing, the aims should be:

1. Give enough information for a reader to unambiguously find a paper
2. Give enough information for citation engines to unambiguously know which paper is cited
3. Present the citations in the format required by the publisher
4. Keep citations neat and consistent in style

With regards to this citation:

> D. Bi-Ru and I. C. Lin, "Efficient Map/Reduce-Based DBSCAN Algorithm with Optimized Data Partition," in Cloud Computing (CLOUD), 2012 IEEE 5th International Conference on, 2012, pp. 59-66.

This seems to meet 1–3.

With regards 4, I would say it is not very neat. I would do:

> D. Bi-Ru and I. C. Lin, "Efficient Map/Reduce-Based DBSCAN Algorithm with Optimized Data Partition," in IEEE 5th International Conference on Cloud Computing (CLOUD), 2012, pp. 59–66.

This reads more naturally, avoids repeating the year and uses an [en-dash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash) for the pages (okay, the later is being super-pedantic).

More correctly, you should probably have "in Proceedings of IEEE ..." but I always found that a waste of space.

If you're fighting a page limit, it is common practice to just write the abbreviation for *well known* conferences within the community (e.g., "CLOUD").

However you choose to format the venue, for the other conference/workshop citations, you should then include a similar style. In this case, all venues should include the edition (5th), the full title (International ...) and the abbreviation (CLOUD).

(And on a side note, I highly recommend switching to LaTeX/BiBTeX and pulling your citations from DBLP if you have medium-to-long term plans for researching in an area of Computer Science.)